# Neural network with one neuron not learning from a linear dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm learning about neural networks with tensorflow and I created a linear dataset with 1000 instances. I tried to make a simple neural network with one neuron to learn from it but I don't know why it didn't. Since is a simple linear dataset I thought it was enough one neuron with one weight to update the value(to number 10 in my case). What am I doing wrong? I don't know if the problem is the dataset I created or what?

Here my first attempt:

```
from numpy.random import default_rng
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

rng = default_rng()
X = rng.integers(low=-1000, high=1000, size=(1000,))
X = X.astype(np.float32)
y = X+10

model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(1,)))

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae,
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01),
              metrics=tf.keras.metrics.mean_absolute_error)

model.fit(X, y, epochs=1000, verbose=0)
print(model.evaluate(X, y))

32/32 [==============================] - 0s 962us/step - loss: 1481.1342 - mean_absolute_error: 1481.1342
[1481.1341552734375, 1481.1341552734375]
```

Then I tried add one more layer with one neuron and  still too big.

```
from numpy.random import default_rng
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

rng = default_rng()
X = rng.integers(low=-1000, high=1000, size=(1000,))
X = X.astype(np.float32)
y = X+10

model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid, input_shape=(1,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae,
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01),
              metrics=tf.keras.metrics.mean_absolute_error)

model.fit(X, y, epochs=1000, verbose=0)
print(model.evaluate(X, y))


32/32 [==============================] - 0s 952us/step - loss: 443.7854 - mean_absolute_error: 443.7854
[443.7854309082031, 443.7854309082031]
```

But if I change the size of the dataset the neural network learn from it very well.

```
X = np.array([-7., -4., -1., 2., 5., 8., 11., 14.])
y = X + 10
```

Here the output of with one neuron:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 96ms/step - loss: 1.8599 - mean_absolute_error: 1.8599
[1.859947681427002, 1.859947681427002]
```

The output with two neurons:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 92ms/step - loss: 6.7571 - mean_absolute_error: 6.7571
[6.757119655609131, 6.757119655609131]
```

Answer (score 1):

The learing rate is too large, set it to 0.0001 even smaller. A better way is to use **Adam**

```
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae,
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=tf.keras.metrics.mean_absolute_error)
```